# How do I protect Minecraft.exe from Vipre Antivirus?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to solve a problem for a friend who has Vipre Antivirus-- it is contantly deleting minecraft.exe and all of his worlds in the course of normal operation.

Vipre has messed with Minecraft in the past, but as of today it just flat-out deletes minecraft, saying it is a trojan. This also happens every time he downloads it, and he can't find the way to disable Vipre from not deleting it (even though he has told the software it is not a virus and he has run it many times in the past).

How can you get Vipre to not delete Minecraft?

Comment: I hate to state the obvious, but... have him stop using Vipre Antivirus. There are plenty of other completely free AV programs which don't flag MC as a trojan. Also, make sure your friend isn't using a pirated copy, or it may very well have a trojan in it.

Comment: Agreed.  Don't use crap like AVG either.  I believe the most recommended on SuperUser is currently MS Security Essentials.  I've had no problems with it, despite major doubts initially.

Comment: And, it's free!

Comment: Im using Avast a cool AV program and I have no problem on Win7

Comment: It's not just Minecraft and not just Vipre. Whatever they use where I'm contracting now (I use my own laptop so I don't use their tools) is doing the same thing to one guy's VM, marking it as a Trojan and deleting it. Fambida is right - find another program that knows not to whack Minecraft and use it.

Comment: I've never even heard of Vipre Antivirus.

Comment: Send an email to the makers of Vipre Antivirus, and if they don't fix it pronto, then use a different antivirus. To me, a game **this popular** being wrongfully marked as a trojan shows that Vipre Antivirus can't possibly be any good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to their website, you can do this: If you have a false positive that has been quarantined by VIPRE please do the following.

1. Open VIPRE,
2. Click on the Manage tab at the top.
3. Click View Quarantine.
4. Select the Detected False Positive
5. Click the Restore from Quarantine button
6. In the windows that pops up, check both the boxes to add to the Always Allowed list and to Submit  to Sunbelt for Analysis

Good luck!

Comment: This seems like the best way to do this. Virpe has worked well for him and his family so he doesn't want to get ride of it after the paid for it, but he was about to. I'll have him try this.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to simply take off the antivirus; It's basically a virus itself. Vipre is just chomping on his/her computer.

I recommend switching to a new antivirus, such as the Malwarebytes anti-malware program. Even without buying the full version, it kicks those virus' (bleep). It even shows the results in a text file after the viruses are deleted.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can add exceptions using the Always Allowed list. To do this, open VIPRE. Go to the Manage tab. Click View allowed items. Click Add. Here you can add exceptions in multiple ways. Does this solve your problem?